# How can i add a left icon in react native text tag?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a react native project and want to add a left icon in the text tag because it is not working in the Picker tag. The picker i am using comes from :

`react-native-picker/picker`

I tried using it inside the picker tag but no response and even in the  tag it does not work

```
<Text
            leftIcon={RadiusIcon}
            style={{color: colors.BlackColor, fontSize: 18}}>
            {t('radius')}
          </Text>
          <Picker
            selectedValue={radius}
            onValueChange={radius => setRadius(radius)}>
            <Picker.Item label="3 Miles" value="3 " />
            <Picker.Item label="6 Miles" value="6" />
            <Picker.Item label="9 Miles" value="9" />
            <Picker.Item label="12 Miles" value="12" />
            <Picker.Item label="15 Miles" value="15" />
            <Picker.Item label="18 Miles" value="18" />
          </Picker>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.